# NHibernate 3.2 By Code ClassMapping for Version Property

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, timestamp, version

What is the correct way to map an timestamp column in an SQL Server 2008 database using NHibernate's new code based mappings?

I have the property in my class defined as byte[] and I'm using the following mapping in my ClassMapping file:

```
Version(x => x.RowVersion, mapping =>
   mapping.Generated(VersionGeneration.Always));
```

However, NHibernate is expecting an integer based on this mapping (throws an exception on inserts).  If I explicitly specify  the mapping type as byte[], I get an exception stating: "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Expected type implementing IUserVersionType
Parameter name: persistentType".

What is the proper way to map an auto updating timestamp column with the new NHibernate code based mappings?

---EDIT

I think I have it narrowed down that I need to set the Type on the mapping to BinaryType (an NHibernate Type that implements IVersionType), but BinaryType doesn't have a public constructor...I think I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We also are using `byte[] Version { get; }`  for version implementation.

Here is out mappings:

```
Version(x => x.Version)
            .Nullable()
            .CustomSqlType("timestamp")
            .Generated.Always()
            ;
```

Also for more details please see [this link](http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I'm not using Fluent Nhibernate.  I'm just using the built in code mappings that are new in 3.2  The built in by-code mappings don't have a CustomSqlType

Answer (score 6):

If you grab the NHib source code, there's a class in a test project that will help you with what you need: NHibernate.Test.VersionTest.Db.MsSQL.BinaryTimestamp. Basically, you have to give it a custom type it can use to convert the value. Be default NHib expects the value to be an int (look at seciont 5.1.7 of [the nhib docs](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-timestamp)). If you use an int/bigint as your version column, you will not need a custom type.

The custom class (lifted from NHib source code):

```
public class BinaryTimestamp : IUserVersionType
{
    #region IUserVersionType Members

    public object Next(object current, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        return current;
    }

    public object Seed(ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        return new byte[8];
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return DeepCopy(cached);
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return DeepCopy(value);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        return rs.GetValue(rs.GetOrdinal(names[0]));
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        NHibernateUtil.Binary.NullSafeSet(cmd, value, index);
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public System.Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(byte[]); }
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new[] { new SqlType(DbType.Binary, 8) }; }
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var xbytes = (byte[])x;
        var ybytes = (byte[])y;
        return CompareValues(xbytes, ybytes);
    }

    bool IUserType.Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return (x == y);
    }

    #endregion

    private static int CompareValues(byte[] x, byte[] y)
    {
        if (x.Length < y.Length)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (x.Length > y.Length)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] < y[i])
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (x[i] > y[i])
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static bool Equals(byte[] x, byte[] y)
    {
        return CompareValues(x, y) == 0;
    }
}
```

A sample mapping using that class:

```
public class Car
{
    public virtual long CarId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] LastModified { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id: {0}, Name: {1}, Last Modified: {2}", CarId, Name, LastModified);
    }
}

public class CarMap : ClassMapping<Car>
{
    public CarMap()
    {
        Table("Cars");

        Id(car => car.CarId, mapper => mapper.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        Property(car => car.Name);
        Version(car => car.LastModified, mapper =>
                                             {
                                                 mapper.Generated(VersionGeneration.Always);
                                                 mapper.Type<BinaryTimestamp>();
                                             });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case of a ConventionModelMapper I ended up using the following..

```
ConventionModelMapper mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();

//...other mappings

mapper.Class<Entity>(map => map.Version(e => e.Revision, m =>
                {
                    m.Generated(VersionGeneration.Always);
                    m.UnsavedValue(null);
                    m.Type(new BinaryBlobType());
                    m.Column(c =>
                        {
                            c.SqlType("timestamp");
                            c.NotNullable(false);
                        });
                }));
```